# When to use vim.eval and when to use vim.command in python-vim?

Tags: vim

From vim doc:

```
vim.command(str)                    *python-command*
    Executes the vim (ex-mode) command str.  Returns None.



vim.eval(str)                       *python-eval*
    Evaluates the expression str using the vim internal expression
    evaluator (see |expression|).  Returns the expression result as:
    - a string if the Vim expression evaluates to a string or number
    - a list if the Vim expression evaluates to a Vim list
    - a dictionary if the Vim expression evaluates to a Vim dictionary
    Dictionaries and lists are recursively expanded.
```

I am having trouble to distinguish these two, perhaps it's because I don't understand the difference between expression and command in the first place. An explanation with some examples is very very welcome.

Comment: expression in substitute commands, expression-commands, vim.command, yeah i also stuck at that, when i started with vim... If you really plan to work with vim, you should read the whole help document, which can be found here http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/help.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR: Use `command()` to execute a Vim command for its side effects, and `eval()` to get back a value computed by a Vimscript function.**

Like other programming languages, Vim(script) distinguishes between a *procedure* (which you just invoke, but get nothing back; the interesting thing is the actions it performs), and a *function* (that returns a value, and can optionally also perform actions like a procedure).

#### Example

With `:split foo.txt`, you invoke this to open a file in a window split. The command returns nothing, but its effects can be easily observed (another window opens, a file being edited in there). You'd use `vim.command()` for that.

With `:echo winnr('$')`, you query the number of open windows. The `:echo` prints that value, but if you wanted that in Python, you'd use `vim.eval("winnr('$')")`. (But note that certain Vim properties are already exposed by the Python integration in Vim; you'd only use this for stuff that's not available in Python yet.)

Answer (score 1):

assume you have two strings:

```
"5d"
```

and

```
"5+5"
```

if you call `command()` on those, it is same as in vim press `:`, then input command.

```
"5d" -> remove the 5th line
"5+5" -> move cursor to 10th line
```

if you call `eval()`, vim evaluates the string as vim expression

```
"5d" -> error
"5+5" -> 10
```

Comment: I actually had a issue.. where `vim.eval` works generally find for most strings such as `vim.eval('a:items')`, but if `a:items` happens to contain `BOM` headers, `vim.eval` crashes.. Other people such as @ludovicchabant has also found it here:https://ludovic.chabant.com/devblog/2017/02/25/aaa-gamedev-with-vim/. I wonder if you know of alternate way of evaluating/transfering a variable from the `vimscript` namespace to the python namespace? https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16756/vim-evalaitems-fails-if-aitems-contain-bom-headers